# Can't update EF context entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, t4

I have a project with a `ContextEngine.tt` but without the `.edmx` file:

[image: Proj. Explorer]

This file has all the representations of my database tables, but when I `run the custom tool` to update my `entities` they **do not** change(I change the database but the models do not change).

Can I generate the `.edmx` file from my `ContextEngine.tt` or do something else to update my entities without recreate all?

Comment: Ps: i am a intern : )

Comment: What does it mean "they do not change"? You change your database and then `run the custom tool` and no changes in model files? Are they checked out by the .tt? Is your connection string correct in `ContextEngine.tt`? If you right click on `ContextEngine.tt` select Properties do you see Custom Tool = TextTemplatingFileGenerator attribute?

Comment: The .edmx file is often generated first with an approach called model first - which creates the .edmx from your database. The .edmx can then be modified and it updates your .tt file and that subsequently updates your models. This apporach is called "model first". How did your ContextEngine.tt get there / how was it created?
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205424(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I suppose .tt added by this [tool](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/pull/160#issuecomment-268400544).

Comment: @RolandHalbaksz yes the connection string is ok, i change my database and the model files do not change

Comment: @user1778606 This project was given to me today, and I am alone.

Comment: @RolandHalbaksz that is pretty a cool tool. bookmarked!

Comment: As @user1778606 indicates, this has nothing to do with model first and edmx files - This is a tool for [Code First to an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) where you want to customize the reverse engineer process. You generally use this tool to get up and running with Code First then make all your changes in code and use something like migrations to update the database.

Comment: You can click "Add New Item" in VS, select ADO.NET Entity Data Model, then Code First from Database, then select the tables you want POCOs and Context generated for and it will create them under your templates.

Comment: Ok I will recreate all, i have tons of configuration files and models to rename , blablabla... Thanks for the attention people, can someone close my question please? @SteveGreene.